# Dropbox Sync Api. Not seeing the File on Dropbox the first time round

Tags: android, dropbox

I have a DropboxHelper Class that is handling downloading and uploading from dropbox.
Downloading works fine but when I try to upload from dropbox the first time the code is called. The following Line is false

```
if (dropboxFileSystem.isFile(dropboxPath)) {

}
```

It returns false. Tell the app to try again and this time it sees the file and uploads it to the app. Below is some of the code I am using for the class. Debug seems to incdicate the dropbox api has not completing started / synced the first time

```
public class DropBoxHelper {


public DropBoxHelper(Context pContext) {

        context = pContext;
        defineVariables();

}

    private void defineVariables() {

        dropboxAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext(), DROPBOX_APP_KEY, DROPBOX_APP_SECRET);
        dropboxPath = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, DROPBOX_FILE_NAME);


    }

public boolean importFromDropbox() {

        try {

            dropboxFileSystem = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(dropboxAccountManager.getLinkedAccount());

            if (dropboxFileSystem.isFile(dropboxPath)) {

                DbxFile databaseFileonDropbox = dropboxFileSystem.open(dropboxPath);

                try {

                    // Do Copy

                } finally {

                    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Closing File");
                    databaseFileonDropbox.close();

                }

}
```

Any ideas on why the copy fails first time.
Thanks

Comment: To make sure I understand, you're saying the file *does* exist in Dropbox, but `isFile` is returning false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe you need to use `dropboxFileSystem.awaitFirstSync()` to make sure at least one sync with the server has happened before you try to find the file.

An alternative might be to just call `dropboxFileSystem.open(...)` directly and handle the exception that's raised if the file doesn't exist.